# Can I show more info in Settings > Apps > App Info on Android?

Tags: android

I have the version name in build.gradle, which is displayed in App Info for the app I am working on. I want to show more useful information there. Does Android allow to show more details? For example, if I want to display the version of an external library, I can hardcode them in json file. There is a way to get parse the json file in the build.gradle. I want to show the parsed values in "App Info".

Can someone please let me know if this is possible? As far as my memory goes, Android has a restriction on showing only version details there.

Comment: No, you can't show any custom information there as far as I know. Most apps have some kind of "About" section (sometimes in the same place they put their settings) where they do things like credit open source libraries.

Comment: Thank you, Karakuri. That is what I thought. Thank you for confirming.